# Java - Converting String to char[]

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, char

I need some help with my code. I want to convert a String object to a char[], using the method toCharArray(), but I can't get it to work.

I have this function in a class named Wordlist:

```
static public char[] Contains(String w)
  {
     if (list.contains(w)) return w.toCharArray();
         else return null;
  }
```

And I call the function with the string variable res:

```
char[] result = new char[4];
result = WordList.Contains(res);
```

Then it seems to return null because the value of result is null. But if change Contains to the following:

```
static public char[] Contains(String w)
      {
         if (list.contains(w)){
            System.out.println(w.toCharArray());
          }
         else return null;
      }
```

Then it prints the string. How is that possible ? What's wrong with my function ?

Comment: What is the type of `list`? What is the value of `res`?

Comment: Just a note, you don't need to initialise result, since you are assigning it on the next line

Comment: the statement after 'if (list.contains(w))' doesn't return anything -> won't compile

Comment: btw, the second version of `Contains` doesn't even compile.

Comment: Your second code will give compilation error !

Comment: Please use the Java conventions: method names should start with lower case.

Comment: Also: try to avoid static fields (list).

Comment: It should still give compilation error after the edit

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve but:

a) read about java naming conventions

b) List<> (and few others in java.util) has a method called .contains (so calling yours Contains causes confusion)

c) do you really want to return null in your "Contains" method?

d) the list (I presume you mean java.util.List) is never declared nor initialized

e) I presume res is a String. it is never declared not initialized.

This should give you an idea :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

  String str = "someString";
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

  list.add(str);
  char[] charArray = containsString(str,list);
  System.out.println(charArray);
}
public static char[] containsString(String str, List<String> list)
{
   if (list.contains(str)) return str.toCharArray();
       else return null;
}
```

Comment: Consider to use a Set insteand of a List.

Comment: Good idea, I agree, since Sets do not allow repetition. I used a list because I assumed he needed a list. Thank you tho.

Comment: Sets are also typically more efficient when checking "contains". (HashSet: O(1), ArrayList: O(n))